# verifying login data from server in WP8

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm in need to provide authentication for my application..and by using email-id and password i need to post and put the data.. i'm new for WP8, so any one can gudie me how to provide authentication..

[image: My Page Design]

when i click `login` button.. it should verify the email id and password from the url(server) and should redirect to new page..

My XAML Code..

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="26,79,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="E-Mail ID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="26,159,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="75" Margin="141,49,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292" InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="141,139,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292" InputScope="Password"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_loin" Content="Log-In" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Click="btn_loin_click" Margin="141,254,0,0"/>
```

The Below Code for registering the user works fine... i need to use the registered user to do the next sequence of functions like ADD/Delete etc..

My Register btn_Click Code..

```
public void btn_register_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            register = populateRegisterDetails();
            var objid = App.Current as App;
            string registerDetails = GetJsonSerializeObject(register);
            this.register = client.addNewRegistration(registerDetails);           
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HomePage.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

My Code work well by passing email and password statically.....

//Adding NEw Organization..

```
public Organization addNewOrganization(string organizationDetails)
    {

    String email="far@c.com";
    String password ="qq";

    JsonClient client = new JsonClient();
    string servicePath = ORGANIZATION_SERVICE + "?"+"email="+email+"&"+"sig="+password;
    Organization organizationregisteredDetails = client.Post<Organization>(servicePath, organizationDetails);
    return organizationregisteredDetails;
}
```

My default Post Method code works fine.....

```
public T Post<T>(string servicePath, string result)
        {

            string serviceURL = REST_URI + servicePath;
            Uri URI = new Uri(serviceURL);
            System.Net.WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
            webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += this.sendPostCompleted;
            webClient.UploadStringAsync(URI, HTTP_POST, result);
            return default(T);
        }
```

I would be helpful if any one guide me..

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: sorry i don't how to start it..

Comment: i had updated the post please check it..